# What is the name for functions leading up a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

I have the following limit of a rectangle function:

$ \text{rect}(t) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty, n \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(2t)^{2n}+1}$

For a fixed interval over $t$, I can generate instantiations of this function by varying $n$. As $n$ increases, this converges to the rectangle/pulse function.  Suppose now I form a set of the functions generated by different values of $n$ of which $n$ is not equal to infinity.  Is there a name for a member of this set?

Comment: I think the typical way to do it would be to just define $f_n(t) := \frac{1}{(2t)^{2n}+1}$ and $\text{rect}(t) := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(t)$

Comment: Its funny you mention that, I am using that exact notation for a writeup i am doing.  I'd like to know though if that set or its members has a special name since its not just a general set of items.

Comment: I don't think so.  It's the same way for sequences of numbers - if you define a sequence by, say, $x_n := (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ there's no canonical way to refer to any member of the sequence.